# JUnit throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/MatcherAssert

Tags: java, maven, exception, junit, hamcrest

I'm coding tests using **JUnit 4.11** and **Hamcrest 1.1** with the following configuration:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.11</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
  <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

And when I run them, the following exception appears:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/MatcherAssert
```

In a line containing:

```
assertThat(obj, hasProperty('id', 1L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `hamcrest-library` instead of `hamcrest-all`. `hamcrest-all` is not meant to be used with a dependency manager because it is an uber-jar that contains `hamcrest-core` and `hamcrest-library`. The following snippet should work.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.12</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
  <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
  <version>1.3</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Junit has its own dependency with `org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3:compile`.

Problem was fixed by changing the dependencies to:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.11</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
  <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
  <version>1.3</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```